# Python-Selenium hangs at random points

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using python selenium version 3.141.0 and latest chrome driver to iterate through some pages of a website. The code works but unfortunately chrome driver hangs at random points. I have tried restarting and updating to latest packages however the issue remains. Any thoughts?

```
page_link_list=[]
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/chromedriver')
for page in page_link_list:
    driver.get(page)
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        p_element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'clip-card')
        for ele in p_element:
            page_link_list.append(ele.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('ng-href'))
        
    except:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        
        p_element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'clip-card')
        for ele in p_element:
            page_link_list.append(ele.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('ng-href'))
        
        p_element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'clip-card')
        for ele in p_element:
            page_link_list.append(ele.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('ng-href'))
        
driver.quit()
```

Comment: is it hanging because the time.sleep() is not property taking into account loading times of pages? -- therefore either increase the time.sleep value or use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706072/python-selenium-webdriverwait

Comment: thanks Andrew, will amend the time.sleep and see how it goes